# Добавление Элементов

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Почему не добавляются элементы на экран если они находятся в функции

```
def onActivated():
  s=combo.currentText()
  print(s)

  comb = QComboBox(root)
  comb.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])

  comb.move(50, 250)
  comb.activated[str].connect(onActivated)
btn = QPushButton('Button',root)
btn.resize(100,30)
btn.clicked.connect(onActivated)
btn.move(50, 50)
```

часть кода которое по идеи должна добавлять `QComboBox`
дополнил

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def onActivated(event):
    s=combo.currentText()
    print(s)

    comb = QComboBox(root)
    comb.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])

    comb.move(50, 250)
    comb.activated[str].connect(onActivated)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root=QMainWindow()
QToolTip.setFont(QFont('Times', 10))
#menu
combo = QComboBox(root)
combo.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva",
                    "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
combo.move(50, 150)
#кнопка
btn = QPushButton('Button',root)
btn.resize(100,30)
btn.clicked.connect(onActivated)
btn.move(50, 50)
#btn.setToolTip('Это кнопочка')
#root.setToolTip('Я основное окно') виджет для подсказки основного окна
root.resize(400,300)
root.setWindowTitle('Tester')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Вызов функции у вас привязан к нажатию на кнопку. При нажатии на кнопку функция вызывается?

Comment: Приведите код полностью. Где создается `root`, используется ли компоновщик?

Comment: @insolor да вызывается т.е. выписывает значение s но 'QComboBox'

Comment: @mkkik дополнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавайте все виджеты до запуска цикла обработки событий. А появление виджета по событию можно осуществлять изменением его `Visible` - свойства.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def onActivated(event):
    s=combo.currentText()
    print(s)

    comb.setVisible(True) # делаем видимым
    comb.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
    # comb.activated[str].connect(onActivated) # вот это точно так задумано?


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root=QMainWindow()
QToolTip.setFont(QFont('Times', 10))
#menu
combo = QComboBox(root)
combo.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva",
                "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
combo.move(50, 150)

comb = QComboBox(root) # создание виджета
comb.move(50, 250) 
comb.setVisible(False) # скрываем до вызова функции

#кнопка
btn = QPushButton('Button',root)
btn.resize(100,30)
btn.clicked.connect(onActivated)
btn.move(50, 50)

root.resize(400,300)
root.setWindowTitle('Tester')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD** Добавление виджета по событию с использованием компоновщика.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def onActivated(event):
    s=combo.currentText()
    print(s)
    box.addWidget(comb) # добавляем виджет
    comb.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root = QWidget() # QMainWindow не обязателен

box = QVBoxLayout() # вертикальный компоновщик

combo = QComboBox() # можно создавать без parent
combo.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
combo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed) # фиксируем размеры, чтобы не растягивались по ширине окна
box.addWidget(combo) # добавляем виджет в компоновщик

comb = QComboBox() # просто создаем виджет, никуда его не помещаем
comb.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

btn = QPushButton('Button')
btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
btn.clicked.connect(onActivated)

box.addWidget(btn)
root.setLayout(box) # связываем компоновщик с главным виджетом

root.resize(400,300)
root.setWindowTitle('Tester')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Нет так не задумано просто от предыдущего скопировал) А как нибудь чтобы именно добавление было нельзя я так понимаю только видимым сделать?

Comment: @Дмитрий, обновил ответ

Comment: а как по вашему мнению будет профитнее сделать?

Comment: Что именно сделать? И что вы подразумеваете под выгодой?

Comment: @Дмитрий: проблема с кодом в вопросе, вероятно, отсутствие `box.addWidget(comb)` и всё.

Comment: @mkkik ну вплане что лучше будет сдетать так как в первом варианте или во втором

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Ваш пример просто учебный. Вообще, динамически добавлять виджеты - не лучшее занятие. В реальном ЮИ лучше использовать механизмы активации/деактивации элементов.

Comment: @mkkik благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите по клику на кнопку добавлять ещё один `comboBox`, правильно?

Лучше всего будет определить собственный объект, который будет компоновать ваши виджеты и обрабатывать их события:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

# Скомпонуем все нужные нам виджеты в одном объекте:
class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_button = QPushButton("Button", self)
        self.m_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.m_combo.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
        # Пусть наш виджет сам занимается размещением своих дочерних виджетов:
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.m_button)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.m_combo)

        self.m_button.clicked.connect(self.slotOnClick)

    # Определим слот-обработчик нажатия кнопки:
    def slotOnClick(self):
        # Создаём новый QComboBox
        addedCombo = QComboBox(self)
        # Заполняем его значениями:
        addedCombo.addItems(["Ubuntu", "Mandriva", "Fedora", "Arch", "Gentoo"])
        # Размещаем на нашем виджете:
        self.layout().addWidget(addedCombo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wgt = MainWidget()
    wgt.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Теперь при каждом нажатии на кнопку у вас будет создаваться новый объект `comboBox`.